# Retrofit response parsing suggestion

Tags: android, json, gson, retrofit

I am parsing the JSON response in retrofit model classes.

My issue is that the response is not constant means some time it will come with 2 params and some time more than that,

exp:

1st response:

```
{
    "error": true,
    "data": {
        "order_id": [
            "Order Id does not exists"
        ]
    },
    "code": 500
}
```

2nd response :

```
{
    "error": false,
    "data": [
        "Order #P have sent successfully"
    ],
    "code": 200
}
```

So in first response if the order id is not there than in response i will get order_id as a key but in 2nd response I will not get because it is success.

*** I can solve this issue by asking the back end guy to change the response but if in case, any other prefixed api response, if I will get this kind of result then how will I handle that??

Comment: Simply use GSON. It will handle all of your stuff..!!

Comment: But in that case, I am getting retrofit error, if GSON is not able to handle the response; in error case, I need the response result too which is "data": {
        "order_id": [
            "Order Id does not exists"
        ]
    }

Comment: I am afraid that you have to change json structure.

Comment: If you getting RetrofitError you still can obtain response body and parse it using GSON.

Comment: Two answers are good. But I would argue with BE to have consistent response. That would be my choice

Answer (score 1):

You can use model class like this :

```
public class ResponseModel {
    private boolean error;
    private int code;
    private JsonElement data;

    // Setters, getters, etc. ...
}
```

Then you can check for error and code value and handle data object in the way you like. Both cases you mention will work with this model.

You can even serialize this `data` variable to some another model class when you will know what data you have inside.

Answer (score 1):

For this case you should write custom `Deserializer` and check if `data` is array or jsonobject.

IMHO in general the idea of using same key for holding error info and non-error info is bad.